# Mapping POJO into Datastore Entity

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Supposing you have this POJO:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    @Embedded
    private Address newAddress; 
    @Child
    private Address oldAddress;
}
```

And I need to convert it into a `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity` object. Properties `name` and `age` are easily mapped into a property of Entity, also `newAddress` would be a `EmbeddedEntity`. Let's say oldAddress is to be stored as a Entity of its own, just having a relationship that it is a child of `User`.

I would do something like:

```
Entity userEntity = ...

userEntity.setProperty("name", name);
userEntity.setProperty("age", age);

EmbeddedEntity ee = ...
e.setProperty("newAddress", ee);

Entity oldAddress = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey(e.getKey, "Address", user.getOldAddress.getId()));

userEntity.setProperty("oldAddress", oldAddress.getKey());
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, just use [JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships). Seriously!

Comment: Peter, I'm not re-inventing the wheel. :-) Well, I can think if the authors of Objectify or Twig thinks to just use the JDO then Objectify or Twig may not have been there. :-)